# Embedded Perl script in Linux shell

Tags: linux, bash, perl, shell

Can I invoke Perl script from Unix shell? For example I have bash script in form like:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo This is bash

i=12
echo $i

perl <<__HERE__
print "This is perl\n";
my \$i = $i;
print ++\$i . "\n";


echo This is bash again
echo $i
```

Above is just an example.

Is it possible to pass variables from bash to script? Hope I expressed myself correctly and properly. I need to call Perl script which will take values from bash script and use them and then return processed results.

Comment: You forgot to end your `__HERE__`.

Comment: Why wouldn't you have a separate Perl script? I'm just curious.

Comment: i am just exploring options ... probably it is good idea to just call script from shell : perl path/myscript.pl is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the dollar signs need escaped.  It makes for an ugly, error prone Perl script.  Use environmental variables.

```
#!/bin/bash

export i=12
readarray results < <(perl <<-'__HERE__'
        my $i = $ENV{'i'};
        print "$i\n";
        $i += 1;
        print "$i\n";
        __HERE__
)
for r in "${results[@]}"; do echo $r; done
```

The quotes around **HERE** prevents bash from doing variable substitution. The "-" allows the here is document to be indented it tabs.

While this is a nice exercise in the finer points of Bash, why not just code in Perl or Bash alone?  Bash does regular expressions, arrays, etc.  And Perl can do everything Bash can.

Comment: Ok this is great, one question though : How can i return values back ? My scripts does something and then return back hash with processed data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to call a Perl script in Shell script. Make sure Perl script is executable and the first line is `#!/usr/bin/perl`.

```
#!/bin/sh

/path/to/perlscript/scriptName.pl arg1 arg2
```

`arg1 arg2 ..` are the arguments if you need to pass any.

You can set the PATH and call the script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/path/to/perlscript/

${PATH}test.pl
```